# Export from datagridview to excel using XML in vb.net

Tags: excel, xml, vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to use XML to export the data from a datagridview to an excel file. Below is the code that I have written

```
    Dim fs As New IO.StreamWriter(FileName, False)

        With fs
            .WriteLine("<?xml version=""1.0""?>")
            .WriteLine("<?mso-application progid=""Excel.Sheet""?>")
            .WriteLine("<ss:Workbook xmlns=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"">")
            .WriteLine("    <ss:Styles>")
            .WriteLine("        <ss:Style ss:ID=""1"">")
            .WriteLine("            <ss:Font ss:Bold=""1""/>")
            .WriteLine("        <ss:/Style>")
            .WriteLine("    <ss:Worksheet ss:Name=""WCRPaymentLog"">")
            .WriteLine("        <ss:Table>")


            For x As Integer = 0 To dgReport.Columns.Count - 1
                .WriteLine("            <ss:Column ss:Width=""{0}""/>", dgReport.Columns.Item(x).Width)
            Next
            .WriteLine("            <ss:Row ss:StyleID=""1"">")

            For x As Integer = 0 To dgReport.Columns.Count - 1
                .WriteLine("                <ss:Cell>")
                .WriteLine(String.Format("                  <ss:Data ss:Type=""String"">{0}</ss:Data>", dgReport.Columns.Item(x).HeaderText.Trim))
                .WriteLine("                </ss:Cell>")
            Next
            .WriteLine("            </ss:Row>")

            For intRow As Integer = 0 To dgReport.RowCount - 2
                .WriteLine(String.Format("          <ss:Row ss:Height=""{0}"">", dgReport.Rows(intRow).Height))

                For intCol As Integer = 0 To dgReport.Columns.Count - 1
                    .WriteLine("                <ss:Cell>")
                    .WriteLine(String.Format("                  <ss:Data ss:Type=""String"">{0}</ss:Data>", dgReport.Item(intCol, intRow).Value.ToString.Trim))
                    .WriteLine("                </ss:Cell>")
                Next
                .WriteLine("            </ss:Row>")
            Next

            .WriteLine("        </ss:Table>")
            .WriteLine("    </ss:Worksheet>")
            .WriteLine("</ss:Workbook>")
            .Close()
        End With
```

When I am trying to run this code, it executes properly, but while opening the generated file, it gives error: Strict Parse Error.

The error log is generated as below:
XML PARSE ERROR:  Undefined namespace
  Error occurs at or below this element stack:
    (Stack is empty--error occurs at or below top-level element.)

Can any one help me please where I am making mistake.

Also I want to code like this way if the file exists, then It will add a new sheet in the code and write the table in that sheet. Can anyone help me to know how to do it because this code overwrites the existing file.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Xml Linq :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Public Class Form1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim xml As String = "<?xml version=""1.0""?><?mso-application progid=""Excel.Sheet""?><ss:Workbook xmlns:ss=""abc"" xmlns:urn=""schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"">" & _
            "<ss:Styles><ss:Style ss:ID=""1""><ss:Font ss:Bold=""1""/></ss:Style></ss:Styles ></ss:Workbook>"

        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml)

        Dim workbook As XElement = doc.Root
        Dim ssNs As XNamespace = workbook.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("ss")

        Dim worksheet = New XElement(ssNs + "Worksheet", New XAttribute(ssNs + "Name", "WCRPaymentLog"))
        workbook.Add(worksheet)

        Dim table = New XElement(ssNs + "table")
        worksheet.Add(table)

        For x As Integer = 0 To dgReport.Columns.Count - 1
            Dim column As XElement = New XElement(ssNs + "Column", New XAttribute(ssNs + "Width", dgReport.Columns.Item(x).Width))
            TAB()
        Next

        Dim row As XElement = New XElement(ssNs + "Row", New XAttribute(ssNs + "StyleID", 1))
        table.Add(row)
        Dim cell As XElement
        For x As Integer = 0 To dgReport.Columns.Count - 1
            cell = New XElement(ssNs + "Cell", New XElement(ssNs + "Data", New Object() {New XAttribute("Type", "String"), dgReport.Columns.Item(x).HeaderText.Trim}))
            row.Add(cell)
        Next

        For intRow As Integer = 0 To dgReport.RowCount - 2
            row = New XElement(ssNs + "Row", New XAttribute(ssNs + "Height", dgReport.Rows(intRow).Height))
            table.Add(row)
            For intCol As Integer = 0 To dgReport.Columns.Count - 1
                cell = New XElement(ssNs + "Cell", New Object() {New XAttribute("Type", "String"), dgReport.Item(intCol, intRow).Value.ToString.Trim})
                row.Add(cell)
            Next
        Next

        doc.Save(FILENAME)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you! While opening the generated file I am getting 3 options: As an XML Table, As a Read-Only Workbook and Use the XML Source task pane. I am choosing the first option. After opening the file, it only has the headers and data type in the sheet and that too row wise not column wise, am I missing anything?

Comment: The xml file is text so you can open in notepad.  I just copied your code with a few corrections in the header to fix some namespace errors.  You should be able in notepad to see if the data is in the xml file.

Comment: The XML file contains correct data when opened in notepad, but while opening in excel it doesn't show. Am I missing something here? or my excel has some issues? I am unable to understand, please help.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Open Xml format.  Do you have an example that you can compare against?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to create an Excel 2003 SpreadsheetML file.

You indicated that you received this error on opening the file in Excel

> XML PARSE ERROR: Undefined namespace Error occurs at or below this element stack: (Stack is empty--error occurs at or below top-level element.)

This leads me to this line:

```
.WriteLine("<ss:Workbook xmlns=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"">")
```

Here you are using the namespace alias "ss:", but it is not defined.  Furthermore, that tag should look like the following.

```xml
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:Spreadsheet"
   xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
   xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
   xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:Spreadsheet"
   xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
```

For more information, see:

[OfficeTalk: Dive into SpreadsheetML (Part 1 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/officetalk2003/bb226687(v=office.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[OfficeTalk: Dive into SpreadsheetML (Part 2 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/officetalk2003/bb226693(v=office.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Edit:

You may also find using VB's Xml Literals to be an easier way to construct the file.  The tutorial video [[How Do I:] Create Excel Spreadsheets using LINQ to XML?](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/ASP-NET-Site-Videos/how-do-i-create-excel-spreadsheets-using-linq-to-xml) may be beneficial to review.